# Cost analyzer tools

Tags: gas, tools

I've being using the hardhat-gas-reporter in order to evaluate the costs of my smart contracts. Do you know any other tool that could help in this purpose? Is there some tool that shows the cost of each line of contract so as we can see where we should concentrate effort?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tools that break down the gas cost line by line unfortunately.  I was able to find this [compilation of gas optimization articles though.](https://github.com/iskdrews/awesome-solidity-gas-optimization)  Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).